# Rails jbuilder append attributes to existing json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, jbuilder

I have a jbuilder template like below:

```
json.flights @campaign.flights do |flight|
  json.partial! 'flights/show', collection: @campaign.flights, as: :flight

  json.has_delivered flight.has_delivered?
end
```

It throws an error after rendering the partial when it tries to render has_delivered.
`"can't convert String into Integer"`

Does anyone know how to render this?